# UDP Client Server invalid argument

Tags: c, sockets

I have a server that is supposed to send information to a client after receiving a message from the client (echo server). Below is the code that is producing an errno 22 which i looked up as "invalid argument". I am trying to understand which argument is invalid because my client sends a message with the same arguments

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
//#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // port to start the server on
    int SERVER_PORT = 8877;

    struct timeval server_start, client_start;

    // socket address used for the server
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;

    // htons: host to network short: transforms a value in host byte
    // ordering format to a short value in network byte ordering format
    server_address.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    // htons: host to network long: same as htons but to long
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    // create a UDP socket, creation returns -1 on failure
    int sock;
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("could not create socket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // bind it to listen to the incoming connections on the created server
    // address, will return -1 on error
    if ((bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address,
              sizeof(server_address))) < 0) {
        printf("could not bind socket\n");
        return 1;
    }


    // socket address used to store client address
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;
    int client_address_len = 0;



    // run indefinitely
    while (true) {
        char buffer[500];

        printf("problem here \n");

        int len=0;
        // read content into buffer from an incoming client
        if (len = recvfrom(sock, &client_start, sizeof(client_start), 0,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address,&client_address_len)<0){

               printf("failed: %d\n", errno);
               return 1;
         }

        // inet_ntoa prints user friendly representation of the
        // ip address
        //buffer[len] = '\0';


        gettimeofday(&server_start);



        int send = 0;

        // send same content back to the client ("echo")
        if(send = sendto(sock, &server_start, sizeof(server_start),0,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address,
               &client_address_len)<0){

             printf("failed: %d\n", errno);
             return 1;
        };


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most likely it's due to what it says -- one or more of the arguments to sendto() call isn't valid.  It's impossible to say which one though, since you didn't post the code that sets the values of those arguments.  If I had to guess, my first guess would be that `client_address` doesn't contain a valid IP address in it, or perhaps `sock` isn't a valid file descriptor of a UDP socket.

Comment: Btw you might want to add a pair of parentheses in your if statement, to make it explicit (to both human readers and the compiler) that you meant `if ((send=sendto(...)) < 0) {...}` and not `if (send = (sendto(...)<0)) {...}`

Comment: thank you for your response. I have edited the code and added the full source

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to understand which argument is invalid

No argument is invalid. You got a false positive on your error testing.

```
if (len = recvfrom(sock, &client_start, sizeof(client_start), 0,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address,&client_address_len)<0){
if(send = sendto(sock, &server_start, sizeof(server_start),0,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address,
       &client_address_len)<0){
```

Usual problem. Operator precedence. Try this:

```
if ((len = recvfrom(sock, &client_start, sizeof(client_start), 0,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address,&client_address_len))<0){
if((send = sendto(sock, &server_start, sizeof(server_start),0,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address,
       &client_address_len))<0){
```

Comment: Define 'did not work'. What happened instead? Another error? If so, what?